Automating wing flap animation for a bee
I'm new to animation and I want to make this bee flap its wings. There are four wings in total. They are not currently paired: the front wings flap between 30° and -30° while the back wings remain at 0°, then they alternate every 3 frames with the back wings at 30° and the front wings at 0°. For the first 2-3 movements, I manually set the values for the X-axis. How can I automate the flapping of the wings?
I'm also temporarily adding the blend file to the bee in the edit if anyone can take a look and suggest if I need to pair them/ change their origins.



If you want to make the animations cyclic, select the 4 rings and ShiftE > Make Cyclic:

It will automatically assign a Cycles modifier to the tracks that have some keyframes, you can check it in the Graph Editor (as you see in the modifier, if necessary you can restrict the frame range of the modifier):

